# how to link rails and angular js for developing single page applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

I know both ruby on rails and angular js, But I don't know how to link both 
could you tell me how can I link both for developing single page applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gem angularjs-rails

put in the gemfile

gem 'angularjs-rails'

Add the following directive to your JavaScript manifest file (application.js):

//= require angular
If you desire to require (optional) Angular files, you may include them as well in your JavaScript manifest file (application.js). For example:

//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-resource
To use the 'unstable' branch, add the following directive to your JavaScript manifest file (application.js):

//= require unstable/angular2

Comment: Thanks you   @Nilton

Comment: I forgot to tell just one more thing, if you want to use de notify.js that you downloaded from the internet, you can put in vendor/assets and you have to configure the config/initializers/assets.rb, inside this file, you have an example on how to configure (sorry for my bad english).